# Subcapertas para controllers en Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Quiero organizar un poco mi codigo y quiero poner todos los controladores que pertenecen al administrador en una carpeta dentro de, por ejemplo:

```
controllers/administrador/LogingController.php
```

y en la ruta lo especifico de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::get('administrador/login', 'administrador\LoginController@getLogin');
```

pero me tira error el error: "La clase administrador\LoginController no existe". Probe poniendole el namespace a la clase quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php
 namespace administrador;
 class LoginController extends BaseController{
```

y ya no tira ese error sino: "Class 'administrador\BaseController' not found"

tambien probe con el use app\controllers\BaseController pero sigue tirando el mismo error, tambien probe añadiendo

```
 app_path().'/controllers/administrador',
```

en el global.php y nada, alguna solucion?

Comment: Con todo respeto, podría ser una buena idea invertir ese tiempo en migrar a Laravel 5.x

Comment: @Shaz Quisiera hacerlo, pero se me exige usar esa versión

Comment: Supongo que tu clase `BaseController` existe y que la tienes en el lugar correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la forma, solo hay que añadir

`app_path().'/controllers/administrador',`

y en la ruta se pone el nombre de la clase normalmente sin la ruta

`Route::get('administrador/login', 'LoginController@getLogin');`

Answer (score 0):

**OPCIÓN 1:**

Borras el namespace de la clase.
Y modificas el archivo `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",

        "app/controllers/administrador"
    ]
},
```

Después ejecutas en tu consola `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

**OPCIÓN 2:**

Modificas todos tus controladores y agregas un namespace
Igualmente modificas el archivo `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",     
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\Controllers\\" : "app/controllers"
    }
},
```

Nuevamente necesitas ejecutar en la consola `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Modificas tu directorio de esto:
`app/controllers/administrador`
a esto:
`app/controllers/Administrador`

Y en las rutas utilizas:

```
Route::get('administrador/login', 'App\Controllers\Administrador\LoginController@getLogin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Es super facil, no tienes que tocar el composer.json ni nada por el estilo... solo crea una una nueva carpeta dentro de Controllers, como Controllers/Backend

luego en los controladores que crees dentro de esta nueva carpeta debes agregar el namespace

```
namespace App\Controllers\Backend;
```

Finalmente en las rutas usas algo como

```
Route::get('/', 'Backend\SomeController@someMethod');
```

Luego me cuentas si te funciona.